# Difference between . and ./ when referring to a directory in bash

Tags: bash, shell

What is the difference between `.` and `./` when referring to a directory in bash?

Or does this even have to do with the shell, or the program I'm executing, e.g. when copying a directory using `cp -r`?

Comment: This is not a programming question and should be asked on corresponding https://unix.stackexchange.com/

Comment: There is no difference. A directory named `foo` can also be called `foo/` (resp. `.` and `./`).

Comment: The directory name is a concept of the file system. It does not belong to Bash or `cp`, etc.

Comment: Meanwhile to answer this question - there is no difference, both refer to current working directory

Comment: @ooxi: But be careful if you store such a directory path to a variable. If you combine variables in the way `$mypath/myfile` and `mypath` is a path with trailing slashes, you will end up having two successive slashes in the resulting string. While this won't harm in many cases, it might cause problems occasionally, so my recommendation is to stay away from trailing slashes.

Answer (score 2):

for `.` there is no difference because it's a special hard link directory but for some commands the trailing `/` may be important to indicate it's a directory for example if dir is symlink to a directory : `ls -l dir` will show a symlink, whereas `ls -l dir/` will list it's content.

Comment: And for globbing - echo .* vs echo ./*